# Creating New Account After Old Account Deleted by SO

Tags: discussion, deleted-users

I have been worrying this problem. When users go way crazy, some of them get their accounts peramently deleted and unabled to be used for life. That is just simple, SO is saying "You are breaking our rules too much, we're kicking you out for life." or something like that. But since our question quality is going down (good news for editors!), I have been wondering if any of those people are creating new accounts and continuing to break our rules here at SO. So my question is that are these users (with an account deleted by SO) making new accounts to keep themselves on SO and decrease our question, comment, and answer quality?

Comment: Sometimes, they create new accounts when the original is just Q-Limited or Q-Banned.  Most of the time they are not smart enough to modify the code they are repostng so they are easy to spot.

Comment: I mean users that are banned from SO, which means their accounts were deleted by SO

Comment: Yes I know what you meant.  Some do not even wait to have the accounts deleted before they create sock puppets.

Comment: Those people are too crazy

Comment: My, this isn't suspicious at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People do this all the time, and there isn't really anything we can do about it. All you need to create an SO account is an OpenID, and those are easy to get.

To help reduce this, new users are rate-limited, and consistent bad behavior from an IP address can lead to additional rate limiting for *all* new users from that IP.

If someone is clearly spamming the site with the same content from different accounts, please do feel free to raise an "Other" flag on one of them to let the moderators know what is happening.

Comment: I should point out that the hobbling of new accounts from troublesome locations seems to be very effective at stopping even the most persistent of these users. We just need better ways of identifying them so we can remove these accounts and trigger this hobbling. I still suspect that people creating new accounts to work around questions bans account for a significant fraction of the worst trash we see here each day, and better means of picking up on this could lead to an overall improvement in post quality. The new anti-recidivism measures were a step in that direction.

Comment: Fwiw, you advised a user that is about to, or already is, question-banned.  He'll be back.